# How do I get the node name in XML with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to get the node by his name and not by his item id, at the moment i have this:

```
XmlNode xmlNodoDebug = docWebConfig.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("system.web/compilation");
Response.Write(xmlNodoDebug.Attributes.Item(1).Value); // returns value "true"
```

My XML is the Web.Config of other C# projects:

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" />
```

I want to get the value of that node by his name, "debug".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

xmlNodoDebug.Attributes["debug"].Value;

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use the indexer which accepts a string index:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b823yx9.aspx

```
XmlAttribute attribute = xmlNodoDebug.Attributes["debug"];
```